# How is the limit of $\frac{3 \ln n}{\ln 2 + 5 \ln n} = \frac{3 \ln n}{5 \ln n} = \frac{3}{5}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My homework shows the solution steps of finding the limits to this sequence:
i) $\lim\limits_{n \to+\infty} \frac{\ln \left(n^{3}+2 n+1\right)}{\ln \left(2 n^{5}+n\right)}=\lim\limits_{n \to+\infty} \frac{\ln \left(n^{3}\left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)}{\ln \left(2 n^{5}\left(1+\frac{1}{2 n^{4}}\right)\right)}$
$=\lim\limits_{n \to+\infty} \frac{\ln n^{3}+\ln \left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)}{\ln \left(2 n^{5}\right)+\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2 n^{4}}\right)}$
$=\lim\limits_{n \to+\infty} \frac{3 \ln n}{\ln 2+5 \ln n}=\lim\limits_{n \to+\infty} \frac{3 \ln n}{5 \ln n}=\frac{3}{5}$

and I'm stuck on the last step where it says:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3 \ln n}{\ln 2 + 5 \ln n} = \frac{3 \ln n}{5 \ln n} = \frac{3}{5}.$$

I don't understand how we lose the $\ln 2$ in the next step and also how the result of $\frac{3}{5}$ ends up being the limit.

Could someone please explain? Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I do, but could you explain how that works here with logs? I'm having a really hard time understanding the last 2 steps and how the ln2 is cancelled out and how ab/bc applies to this

Comment: Given $x \neq 0$, since $$\frac{x}{x} = \frac{1}{1} = 1,$$ in $$\frac{3x}{5x}$$ we can strike out $x$ (it "cancels"). What happens to $\log 2$ is a little more involved than I can explain in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

For any given finite $n$, the first $=$ is incorrect, but its relative error has limit $0$. A mathematician would usually write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n}=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\ln n}{\ln 2+5\ln n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac35\frac{1}{1+\frac{\ln 2}{5\ln n}}=\frac35\frac{1}{1+0}=\frac35,$$using the continuity of $\frac35\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 2):

We first show that $\ln n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

$\ln \left(\dfrac{1}{1-n}\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k}$ and so, setting $x=1$ gives $\ln n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

Multiplying both sides of the numerator and denominator by $\dfrac{1}{\ln n}$ gives 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3}{\frac{\ln2}{\ln n}+5}=\dfrac{3}{5}$$ as $\ln n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ by the above proof.

Comment: Your formula for $\ln\frac{1}{1-n}$ only works when $|n|<1$.

Comment: can you quickly explain why (ln2)/(lnn) = 0?

Comment: @AmitYehuda You need to get out of the habit if working $f(n)=L$ when you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$ (or, if you prefer: $f(n)\to L$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @AmitYehuda what do you get when you divide a small number by a really large one? (e.g. $\dfrac{1}{10^{15}}$)?

Comment: a smaller number. is (3/5) the limit because having any number below that would result in the equation breaking? sorry, this is the first day I've ever used natural logs and I guess I keep forgetting that I'm solving for the limit and not the actual equation for n. I appreciate the answers, guys.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{n^3+2n+1}{2n^5+n}=\frac{n^3\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}{n^5\left(2+\frac{1}{n^4}\right)}$$ and $$\frac{\ln(n^3)}{\ln(n^5)}=\frac{3\ln(n)}{5\ln(n)}=\frac{3}{5}$$

Comment: how did you get $\dfrac{n^3+2n+1}{2n^5+n}$?

Comment: @SimonFraser, have you thought of looking at the edits list and clicking on the image with the full task (which the OP deleted after this answer had been posted)?